# How do I change this VBA code to Paste values only

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Merge2MultiSheets()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xSelItem As Variant
    Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xFileName, xSheetName, xRgStr As String
    Dim xBook, xWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xSheetName = "Sheet1"
    xRgStr = "A1:D4"
    Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With xFileDlg
        If .Show = -1 Then
            xSelItem = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
            Set xWorkBook = ThisWorkbook
            Set xSheet = xWorkBook.Sheets("New Sheet")
            If xSheet Is Nothing Then
                xWorkBook.Sheets.Add(after:=xWorkBook.Worksheets(xWorkBook.Worksheets.Count)).Name = "New Sheet"
                Set xSheet = xWorkBook.Sheets("New Sheet")
            End If
            xFileName = Dir(xSelItem & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)
            If xFileName = "" Then Exit Sub
            Do Until xFileName = ""
               Set xBook = Workbooks.Open(xSelItem & "\" & xFileName)
                Set xRg = xBook.Worksheets(xSheetName).Range(xRgStr)
                xRg.Copy xSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                xFileName = Dir()
                xBook.Close
            Loop
        End If
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It's better to include some description of your problem rather than just pasting the code.

Comment: `xxxxxxx.value = xxxxxxx.value`

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.

```
Sub Merge2MultiSheets()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xSelItem As Variant
    Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xFileName, xSheetName, xRgStr As String
    Dim xBook, xWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    Dim vDB As Variant '<~~ new Variable for array
    Dim Target As Range 'new Variable

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xSheetName = "Sheet1"
    xRgStr = "A1:D4"
    Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With xFileDlg
        If .Show = -1 Then
            xSelItem = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
            Set xWorkBook = ThisWorkbook
            Set xSheet = xWorkBook.Sheets("New Sheet")
            If xSheet Is Nothing Then
                xWorkBook.Sheets.Add(after:=xWorkBook.Worksheets(xWorkBook.Worksheets.Count)).Name = "New Sheet"
                Set xSheet = xWorkBook.Sheets("New Sheet")
            End If
            xFileName = Dir(xSelItem & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)
            If xFileName = "" Then Exit Sub
            Do Until xFileName = ""
               Set xBook = Workbooks.Open(xSelItem & "\" & xFileName)
                Set xRg = xBook.Worksheets(xSheetName).Range(xRgStr)
                vDB = xRg '<~~ Put the contents of a range into an array
                'xRg.Copy xSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                Set Target = xSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                Target.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB '<~~ Get the value of an array.
                xFileName = Dir()
                xBook.Close
            Loop
        End If
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```